# Unix stat error "stat: illegal option -- -"

Tags: bash, unix, freebsd, xargs

as I'm pretty new to shell programming I'm completely lost with this error I get:

```
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
```

This error occurs when I run the script on FreeBSD. It works just fine on CentOS.

This is the code I'm using

```
for i in `find "$1" -name "$2" -type f ! -name "$3" -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format="%s" | sort -n| awk {print}`; do 
    size_array[$j]=$i
    ((j=j+1))
```

What is basicaly does is to load size of all files into array. So I will be able to make median of all files sizes. So this should display file size in bytes.

```
stat --format="%s"
```

What syntax sould I use to get rid of this error?

If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a non-standard "long option". Options like `--format` are common on GNU utilities but not standard.  Many of the command-line utilities on Linux come from GNU.

Usually the short option `-f` will work across platforms. However `stat(1)` is non-standard as well!  It appears that for CentOS you need either `--format` or `-c`.

You will need to test the operating system version with something like `uname(1)`.  Unfortunately this is what happens when you use non-standard features.

Edit:

Here is an alternative which should work everywhere and I think does what you need:

```
declare -A size_array
i=0

for fname in $(find "$1" -name "$2" -type f \! -name "$3" -print)
do
    size_array[$i]=$(ls -l "$fname"|awk '{print $5}')
    (( i++ ))
done

echo ${size_array[@]}
```

The `!` is escaped (`\` prefix) because it is a special character in bash.  Rather than using an array count (`$i`) then `+=` could be used to append to the array, but that is only available in later versions of bash.  Yes you could probably do the whole lot in one long line, but there is no advantage to that and it makes it difficult to debug.

Comment: So I guess I will have to rewrite it somehow . Thank you

Comment: @FilipMik: if you are going across platforms between Linux and FreeBSD then you will probably find other incompatibilities.  If the scripts must be portable then I suggest you write conditional code depending on the OS.  There are various environment variables you could use, and the output from `uname(1)`.

Comment: BTW, the backtick `\`` character is deprecated, use `$( ... )` instead because it is easier to read.

Comment: @FilipMik: suggested alternative in post

Comment: Thank you very very much, you helped me a lot :) Was struggling with it a bit

Comment: @FilipMik: if my answer is satisfactory then could you please accept it? (the large tick)